# What program can I use to open .mld (recorded webcam) files?

Tags: software-recommendation, files, webcam

I am looking for a program to open video files with the extension .mld (This is a file from a video recording software I had a long time ago). Does anybody know any programs in Ubuntu that can open such files?

Zoals de titel luidt: ik ben op zoek naar een programma dat videobestanden met de extensie .mld kan openen. Dit is een bestand van een wecbamrecorder die ik vroeger had op Windows. 
Alvast heel erg bedankt.

Answer (score 2):

Try VLC, it can play almost any file video or audio.

```
    sudo apt-get install vlc
```